# Sendgrid-django sending mail with sandbox_mode enabled

Tags: django, email, sendgrid

I have integrated [sendgrid-django](https://github.com/elbuo8/sendgrid-django) to my project, and the emails are working fine and everything looks good.
According to Sendgrid documentation, if I want to test the email without actually sending it i should do something like this:

```
"mail_settings": {
    "sandbox_mode": {
        "enable": True
    }
}
```

So using sendgrid-django I created the email object, left the "body" argument blank to use the sendgrid template, added the sendgrid template_id, substitutions, and then mail_settings:

```
mail = EmailMessage(
    'Subject of my email',
    ' ',
    'fromexample@email.com',
    [toexample@email.com],
    reply_to=[fromexample@email.com],
)
mail.template_id = 'template_id'
mail.substitutions = {
    '-first_name-': 'Ace',
    '-last_name-': 'Ventura'
}
mail.mail_settings = {
    "sandbox_mode": {
        "enable": True
    }
}
```

My email is being sent in any case, so the question is... how can i add those `mail_settings` and get them working??

Answer (score 1):

Apparently when using sendgrid-django we need `.mail` instead of `.mail_settings`, so the solution for this would be:

```
mail.mail = {
    "sandbox_mode": {
        "enable": True
    }
}
```

That way the email does not get sent but we can see if the status is 2XX and everything is fine.